Turing Machine to Generate the Sequence 10110111011110... of increasing number of symbols
Designing a Turing Machine to Generate the Sequence 10110111011110... on a Blank Tape
Question:
I am working on designing a Turing machine that, when given a blank tape, generates the sequence 10110111011110..., where the pattern involves increasing the number of 1s between each 0. Specifically, the desired output sequence starts with 1, followed by 0, then 11, another 0, then 111, and so on, with the number of 1s increasing by one after each 0.
Here is the pattern I aim to generate:

1
0
11
0
111
0
1111
0
and so forth.

Current Approach:
I have developed a partial transition function that works correctly when the input tape is initialized with 10 or other non-blank initial configurations. However, when starting with a blank tape, my current Turing machine produces the incorrect output: 10110110..., which does not follow the intended pattern.
Transition Function:
Here is the transition function I have so far (formatted as (current_state, read_symbol) -> (new_state, write_symbol, direction)):
\begin{align*}
(q1, B) & \rightarrow (q1, B, >) \\
(q1, 1) & \rightarrow (q1, 1, >) \\
(q1, \_) & \rightarrow (q2, 1, <) \\
(q2, B) & \rightarrow (q2, B, <) \\
(q2, 1) & \rightarrow (q2, 1, <) \\
(q2, \_) & \rightarrow (q3, \_, >) \\
(q3, B) & \rightarrow (q4, d, >) \\
(q3, 1) & \rightarrow (q5, e, >) \\
(q4, B) & \rightarrow (q4, B, >) \\
(q4, 1) & \rightarrow (q4, 1, >) \\
(q4, \_) & \rightarrow (q6, B, <) \\
(q5, B) & \rightarrow (q5, B, >) \\
(q5, 1) & \rightarrow (q5, 1, >) \\
(q5, \_) & \rightarrow (q6, 1, <) \\
(q6, B) & \rightarrow (q6, B, <) \\
(q6, 1) & \rightarrow (q6, 1, <) \\
(q6, d) & \rightarrow (q3, B, >) \\
(q6, e) & \rightarrow (q3, 1, >) \\
(q7, B) & \rightarrow (q7, B, <) \\
(q7, 1) & \rightarrow (q7, 1, <) \\
(q7, \_) & \rightarrow (q8, \_, >)
\end{align*}
Problem:
The transition function seems to only work partially and fails to generate the increasing pattern of 1s when starting from a blank tape. I suspect that the issue lies in how the initial states and transitions are configured, particularly when the tape is blank at the beginning. The current setup works when initialized with 10 but does not produce the correct sequence from a completely blank tape.
Request:
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to modify the transition functions to correctly generate the desired sequence when starting from a blank tape. Specifically, I am looking for:

A detailed explanation of what might be going wrong with my current transition functions.
Any proposed modifications or alternative transition functions that would allow the Turing machine to produce the correct pattern from a blank tape.
Insights into common strategies or design principles for creating Turing machines that generate specific sequences like this.

Additional Information:
I am using the Turing Machine Simulator available at turingmachinesimulator.com. The code I am currently using is structured as follows:
name: Duplicate input (1 as end marker) \\
init: q1 \\
accept: q8 \\

q1,B \\
q1,B,> \\
q1,1 \\
q1,1,> \\
q1,\_ \\
q2,1,< \\

q2,B \\
q2,B,< \\
q2,1 \\
q2,1,< \\
q2,\_ \\
q3,\_,> \\

q3,B \\
q4,d,> \\
q3,1 \\
q5,e,> \\

q4,B \\
q4,B,> \\
q4,1 \\
q4,1,> \\
q4,\_ \\
q6,B,< \\

q5,B \\
q5,B,> \\
q5,1 \\
q5,1,> \\
q5,\_ \\
q6,1,< \\

q6,B \\
q6,B,< \\
q6,1 \\
q6,1,< \\
q6,d \\
q3,B,> \\
q6,e \\
q3,1,> \\

q7,B \\
q7,B,< \\
q7,1 \\
q7,1,< \\
q7,\_ \\
q8,\_,> \\

Thank you in advance for your assistance ^^

I didn't read or understand your machine, but note that if it really is the case that you  have something that works with a 10 starting on the tape rather than blanks, it's pretty easy to just add a couple states to write a 10, return to the starting cell then jump into your starting state.

Let me answer question 2 of yours with a Turing machine that hopefully works. The notation $A/B,C$ means you see an $A$, replace it with $B$ and move to the right if $C=R$ or left if $C=L$.

What this does is the following.
It starts by writing a $10$ on the blank tape, moving from $q_0$ to $q_2$. Then it starts copying everything from after the previous $0$ to just before the newly written $0$ (the bottom triangle is basically a copy machine). Once it's done, it returns to $q_0$ and again writes a $10$ (which adds the extra $1$ now required) and repeats.
Here's a turing machine simulator code for you to play with:
name: String with increasing 1s
init: q0
accept: q6



q0,1
q0,1,>

q0,_
q1,1,>

q1,_
q2,0,<

q2,1
q2,1,<

q2,_
q3,_,>

q2,0
q3,0,>

q3,1
q4,X,>

q4,0
q4,0,>

q4,1
q4,1,>

q4,_
q5,1,<

q5,1
q5,1,<

q5,0
q5,0,<

q5,X
q3,1,>

q3,0
q0,0,>

